# Diferencia entre ascii 160 y 32

Tags: if, ascii, booleano

mi pregunta se origino al intentar comparar 2 palabras de diferente origen, una de phpmyadmin y otra de excel, que visualmente se veían exactas pero al ejecutar daba falso[image: Consola Chrome]

la diferencia se puede ver en sublime

[image]

pero entonces en que caso se utiliza el 160 y en que otros el 32

Comment: En el tercer carácter de la segunda cadena (previo a la A) no es un espacio en blanco de tipo ascii 32 `SPACE(U+0020)` sino 160 `NON-BREAKING SPACE(U+00A0)`. Asumiendo que el valor obtenido de phpmyadmin sea el segundo puede ser deberías encodearlo como UTF-8 antes de insertarlo a la DB. Puede ser también cambiar el `COLLATE` de tu DB. O puedes hacer un replace del caracter unicode `U+00A0` por el spacio en blanco `U+0020` al momento de comparar las cadenas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia entre un caracter de espacio "normal" (U+0020) y un caracter de espacio "non-breaking" (U+00A0) es que al procesarse para despliegue en HTML por ejemplo, o en algunos editores de texto hay una diferencia en cuanto al acomodo de las palabras cuando se puede producir un salto de línea, por ejemplo, si se quiere que la cadena
`20 grados` se mantenga en una sola línea, es decir, que el acomodo del texto no cause que se despliegue como

`20`

`grados`

en caso de que el texto exceda el ancho de la pantalla después del `20` y que lleve `grados` a la siguiente línea.

Con el uso del caracter "non-breaking space" (U+00A0) para separar las palabras, se logrará que al exceder el ancho de pantalla, se haga el salto de la cadena

`20 grados`

completa a la siguiente línea y no se divida en 2 líneas de texto.

Esta es la diferencia básica entre ASCII 160 y 32, como lo mencionas en el título de tu pregunta.

En la comparación que estás haciendo la el resultado es falso porque los caracteres de espacio son diferentes después del "9". Para que la comparación resulte en `true`, como dice el comentario de @Kilbunny, puedes reemplazar el espacio "non-breaking" por el espacio en blanco antes de comparar las cadenas.

Comment: gracias por sacarme de la duda ya lo comprobé y si funciona